# How to display the scope property to text input in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm new in AngularJS, and can't do the simple task. I hope that you will help me.
My goal is to display the $scope property "server" from controller to text input in the view when it's loaded:

My controller:

```
(function () {

  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('HomeController', homeController);

  homeController.$inject = ['authService', 'httpService'];

  function homeController(authService, $scope) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.auth = authService;
    $scope.server = SERVER_HOST_NAME;
    console.log ($scope.server);
  }
})();
```

var SERVER_HOST_NAME = "anysite.com"; is global.

And I want, that the text input in the view is display that for loading.

My view is

```
<h4 ng-if="vm.auth.isAuthenticated()">
    You are logged in!
</h4>
<h4 ng-if="!vm.auth.isAuthenticated()">
  You are not logged in! Please <a ng-click="vm.auth.login()">Log In</a> to continue.
</h4>

<div class="container">
  <label>Team city server:</label>

  <input ng-model="server" type="text" />
    <button ng-click="getBuilds()">Extract</button>
</div>
```

I use ng-model to bind my property to textinput, but have no idea why it is not working. I guess this is simple task. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

why you are mixing up both $scope and vm ? use vm and controller as syntax on HTML as follows,

```
 vm.server = SERVER_HOST_NAME;
```

and the HTML would be,

```
<input ng-model="vm.server" type="text" />
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply, I did what you say, but the problem is still apper. The textinput didn't display the vm.server property

Comment: can you console.log and see what is the value of vm.server inside the controller

Comment: I can't undestand, but you solution is worked, I don't know why I can't get this result at the first time, but now is displaying, many thanks to you.